# Why does my python function return none if I have a return for every case?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I can't figure out why this returns none!

I have a return for every branch...

Thanks in advance.

```
def recurPowerNew(base, exp):
    '''
    base: int or float.
    exp: int >= 0

    returns: int or float; base^exp
    '''
    if exp<=0:
        return 1
    elif exp%2==0:
        return recurPowerNew(base*base, (exp/2))

        return base*recurPowerNew(base, (exp-1))


print recurPowerNew(7.62,9)
```

Comment: It isn't _necessary_ here, but it's often _clearer_ to use `if`/`elif`/`else`, instead of `if`/`elif` and then falling off the end of that statement. (That would also have made your actual bug impossible to write.)

Comment: Because you don't have a `return` for every branch. You have two `return`s for the second branch, and none for the third...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of your indentation, the last line of your input is wrong indented.

You should fix it to this:

```
def recurPowerNew(base, exp):
    """
    base: int or float.
    exp: int >= 0

    returns: int or float; base^exp
    """
    if exp <= 0:
        return 1
    elif exp%2 == 0:
        return recurPowerNew(base*base, (exp/2))

    return base*recurPowerNew(base, (exp-1))
```

While we're here, I'll like to point that according to [PEP-257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) it's better to use double quotes than single quotes:

> For consistency, always use """triple double quotes""" around docstrings.